# Angular 2.1.1 and Angular 4.2.4 same code != result

Tags: angular

I'm using exactly the same code in two differents projects with not the same version.

Same code :

Element component

```
@Input()
config: any[] = [];

ngOnInit () {
    console.log(this.config);
}
```

File using Element component

```
const segmentFieldset = [
    {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'From',
        placeholder: 'From',
        name: 'from', 
    },
    {
        type: 'input',
        label: 'To',
        placeholder: 'To',
        name: 'to'
    },
    {
        type: 'date',
        label: 'Begin',
        placeholder: 'Begin',
        name: 'begin'
    }
];

config = {
    segments: [
        { ...segmentFieldset },
        { ...segmentFieldset }
    ]
}

<element [config]="config"></element>
```

Angular 2.1.1 :

console.log return two times : {segments: Array(2)} {segments: Array(2)}

Angular 4.2.4 (the result I want)

console.log return one time : {segments: Array(2)}

I don't understand why Angular 2 return 2 times instead of one.

Comment: can you recreate a plnkr? My guess is your angular 2 project is loading the element component twice.

Comment: @LLai I've deleted and reuploaded the module, and It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted and reuploaded the module, and It's working now...